# Why are the leading whitespaces not being removed when using trim()?

Tags: java, string, trim

I need to have access to java source files and I am using the String's method trim() to remove any leading and trailing whitespaces. However the code which is some scope, for example:

```
if(name.equals("joe")){
   System.out.println(name);
}
```

the white spaces for the printing statement are not being removed completely. Is there a way to be able to remove also these white-spaces please?

Thanks

EDIT: I did use a new variable:

```
String n = statements.get(i).toString().trim();
            System.out.println(n);
```

however the output still looks like this:

```
System.out.println("NAME:" + m.getName());
BlockStmt bs = m.getBody();
List<Statement> statements = bs.getStmts();
for (int i = 0; i < statements.size(); i++) {
    if ((statements.get(i).toString().trim().contains(needed)) & (statements.get(i).toString().trim().length() == needed.length())) {
        System.out.println("HEREEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE");
    }
}
```

Some of the strings are still containing the spaces beforehand

Comment: You do not show the code containing `trim`. Remember that this method returns a new String instance, you need something like `name = name.trim()`. It removes leading and trailing whitespaces: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()

Comment: There is no trim in your statement. Fix your code please.

Comment: I think he's saying that if he calls trim on the code that he posted.

Comment: this is the part of the code, I am then using the trim in another method when I get the source code contents

Comment: @ictStudent: If you have an issue with `trim` you *must* show that part of the code, anything else results in answers just guessing what your problem might be.

Answer (score 5):

You are mistaken.  The `String.trim()` method *does* remove leading and trailing whiteshape entirely.

However, I suspect that your real problem is that you don't know what this really means.  Java strings are immutable, so `trim()` obviously doesn't modify the target `String` object.  Instead, it returns a new `String` instance with the whitespace removed.  So you need to use it as follows:

```
    String trimmed = someString.trim();
```

Answer (score 4):

You must have to assign the result of string. (String [objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) are immutable).

```
name=name.trim();
if(name.equals("joe")){
   System.out.println(name);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As @home mentioned:

```
if(name.equals("joe")){
        String newName = name.trim();
        System.out.println(newName);
}
```

Should work

**EDIT:** I guess that you want to use trim before the condition. My mistake.

```
String newName = name.trim();

if(newName.equals("joe")){
        System.out.println(newName);
}
```

Comment: Surely if `name` has leading whitespaces, the `equals()` method would return false.